# WF bind data from foreign table to combobox

Tags: c#, entity-framework, combobox, workflow-foundation

I'm new to data driven MS programs and I'm trying to build application with WF and EF, but it have problems with data binding, and here is an example.

Here we have some model :

[image: Data model]

And by DetailsView I added PhoneNumberSet to form, and I binded PersonSet to Combobox to display list instead of foreign key.

[image: Data binding preview]

But I don't know what Selected Value field supposed to be (I tried every logic option, but result is always the same)

After compiling this app I can add new records, and fill Number field, but when I select person from dropdown, controls stop to work. I can't switch to different record, save current, add new. Dropdown keeps focused, and only way to close program is by stop debugging.

Comment: how you fill your combobox datasource?List or BindingList?

Comment: Just used dataset as datasource.